# python 2 vs 3 compatibility test with pylint is giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pylint

I'm currently working on migrating our codes from Python 2 to Python 3.
For that, we thought of using `pylint` to check the compatibility test with below code with simple print.

File_1.py

```
print "Hello"
```

File_2.py

```
print("Hello")
```

In above case both will work in Python 2, but `File_1.py` will have a syntax error in Python 3.

When I run pylint on the below files I am getting same report on both files.
Logically `File_2.py` is Python-compatible, then why is pylint showing it as error code **E**?
Am i doing anything wrong...?

```
pylint --py3k File_1.py File_2.py
No config file found, using default configuration

************* Module File_1
E: 1, 0: print statement used (print-statement)
************* Module File_2
E: 1, 0: print statement used (print-statement)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -40.00/10 (previous run: -40.00/10, +0.00)
```

Code and python2.7 pylint Output
[image]

Python3.7 pylint Output
[image: Python3.7 pylint Output]

Python2 pylint version

[image: pylit version]

Python3 pylint version

[image]

Comment: I can't repro; but then the `pylint` I have does not support the `--py3k` option. Which version are you running?

Comment: @tripleee i tested it on python-2.7 with pylint-1.9.5

Comment: @tripleee i have added the snapshots for clarity and to show the file content

Comment: Can you try adding `from __future__ import print_function` on top of File2?

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient, outdated version of `pylint`? Pylint 2.11.0, Release date: 2021-09-16: `The python3 porting mode checker and its py3k option were removed. You can still find it in older pylint versions.`

Comment: @Marat,
not working....
If i am not wrong `from __future__ import print_function` is useful to add print functionality accesting parenthesis like in python3

Comment: @RandomDavis, in higher versions we dont have --py3k flag without which we can't check py3 compatability

Comment: @Rao Exactly. But the removal of the `--py3k` flag from Pylint does not mean that you cannot check for Python 3 compatibility. Starting from Pylint version 2.0, the tool is inherently designed to encourage Python 3 compatible code. The specific `--py3k` flag was meant to help in transitioning from Python 2 to Python 3. Therefore, when you run Pylint on your code, it will flag code that is not compatible with Python 3, even without any specific flags for Python 3 compatibility checks. So, again, I am asking why you are using an older version.

Comment: @RandomDavis, in this case of latest version of pylint, it will give complete summary of the lint, but if i use the --py3k it only gives errors specific to py2 & py3 compatability is my assumption. correct me if i am wrong.

More over i am running pylint on `python-2.7` which supports max `pylint 1.9.5` only.
Do you recommend to run pylint of python 2 files with python3 pylint...?

Comment: For my part I would recommend the latest pylint with the `-E` switch, which shows only errors. But really, first, run `2to3` on your code, the tool will do most of the required conversion work for you.

Comment: For example, `2to3 File1.py` shows me how to convert the print statement into the print function, and `2to3 -w File1.py` overwrites the file with the conversion applied.

Comment: I installed Python 3.6 with `pyenv` just so I could `pip install pylint==1.9.5` and it runs on both of your files with no errors. If I remove the `--py3k` option, it shows an error for `File_1.py`, but it's different from the one you report (`E:  1, 0: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello")? (<string>, line 1) (syntax-error)`). Your screen shot suggests that you ran it under Python 2.7 though.

Comment: @tripleee, yes the result is different when we run the pylint in python 2 and python3.What you mentioned is right in python2 it gives the result as per my snapshot but if we run the same in python 3 with pylint option -E then we get only errors and that too what you mentioned.

Currently my code is in python2, and want to know its its compatabile with python3 as well. because we need to support both versions in the code. in future when we shift to complete python3 we can use the advanced python3 concepts.

So do i need to run my pylint in py2 or py3. what do you suggest.

Comment: @joanis While `2to3` certainly copes perfectly with these simple examples, it is not sufficient for reliably porting nontrivial code from Python 2 to Python 3. It gets you there some of the way, but there are many corners where the resulting code is not functionally equivalent. You need good test coverage and a fair amount of time to properly port over code from Python 2 to Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

The error simply means that `pylint` doesn't want you to use `print` *statements* and instead encourages (nay, requires) you to use `print` *function* invocations even in Python 2.7, basically for forward compatibility with Python 3.

If you add `from __future__ import print_function` to the scripts, the error goes away. This basically tells Python that `print` refers to the function (which requires parentheses) and not the (Python 2 only) `print` statement (which accepts them, but does not require them).

In still other words, `print("Hello")` without the `from __future__` import is syntactically equivalent to `print "Hello"` in Python 2.

The alternate workaround is to disable this error, but for porting your code to Python 3 while retaining Python 2 compatibility, you definitely don't want that.

Comment: The fact that this was suggested in a comment yesterday and you rejected it is somewhat puzzling; but it's still the answer.